# I'm new to programming. How do i linear search a number in array, i also have to create a function and pass the array[] and integer through that

Tags: java, arrays, linear-search

```
public static int[] linearSearch(int arr[], int x) {
        
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i]==x) {
            return arr;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static int[] takeInput() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N= s.nextInt();
        int arr[]= new int[N];
        int x=s.nextInt();
        
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
             arr[i]=s.nextInt(); 
        }
        return arr;
    }
        
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
                
    }
```

I'm unable to pass int x that i've taken as input through takeInput, and also linear search won't accept array and int.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what problem you are having doing this -- please edit your question to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int search(int arr[], int x)
    {
        int N = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == x)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
 
    // Driver's code
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int arr[] = { 2, 3, 4, 10, 40 };
        int x = 10;
 
        // Function call
        int result = search(arr, x);
        if (result == -1)
            System.out.print(
                "Element is not present in array");
        else
            System.out.print("Element is present at index "
                             + result);
    }
```

Comment: the purpose of stack overflow is not to provide code solutions but to answer questions. in other words, help OP by explaining what was incorrect in their code. also add explanation of your solution, for the benefit of future devs coming here

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Whatever the purpose of this site, he may be answering for his own purposes.

Comment: no he may not. that is why downvotes are for. so that new contributors like yourself and solution provider may learn how this site operates and what is its purpose. seeing you are here for 3 days, I advise to take the time and learn about this site before rushing to give your opinion

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Your comment is not directed at the questioner or answerer. In that case, the name should be written first. You should learn more about this site.